# how to avoid the overwriting in file writing using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-writing

I have a code for file writing..the data is got it properly in controller.
But the code is working in the for loop..
Iteration is ok.
Disply all the data in controller
Create a file log_date.txt but write only the last data is my problem..

```
$file_path='./application/assets/login/log_'.date'.txt',$data);
if(file_exists($file_path))
{
    write_file(APPPATH'/assets/login/log_'.$todate.'.txt', $data);
}
else
{
    write_file(APPATH'./assets/login/log_'.$todate.'.txt', $data);
}
```

Comment: if the loop working in two times then the two sets of data is generated..bt the last data is write in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that if the file exists, then you want to append the data to it. Otherwise you want to create a file and add the data right? If this is your concern, then you can change the file writing mode with the optional 3rd parameter within the [`write_file`](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html#write_file) function. By default, it is 
`wb` where it overwrites the file. However with the `a` method, you can append a new line to the file without overwriting it.

```
$file_path = APPPATH . "/assets/login/log_.$todate.txt";
if(file_exists($file_path))
{
    write_file($file_path, $data, 'a');
}
else
{
    write_file($file_path, $data);
}
```

Even better, you can just do what you want without the control statement as the `a` mode checks first if the file exists or not, then creates it, otherwise it just appends the data. So just the below part is enough without the control statement.

```
$file_path = APPPATH . "/assets/login/log_.$todate.txt";
write_file($file_path, $data, 'a');
```

**Edit:**

To add each data within a new row when you are running it within a loop, add new line to `$data`:

```
$file_path = APPPATH . "/assets/login/log_.$todate.txt";
write_file($file_path, $data . "\r\n", 'a');
```

Comment: but it append on the same line..I want the data in each iteration on seperate line

Comment: I think I misunderstood you, lets say you have are appending the same data all the time and let it be "asd", after the second loop, does it append on the same line 2x such that "asdasd" or you mean, it just overwrites the last line asd? if you want to add a new line, just add `\n ` to your `$data`. Just like: `$data .= "\n"`

Comment: How? what is the output you are getting, I didn't understand, what is on last line after for instance 5 loops?

Comment: 1~1~800~2015-06-29<br>1~1~500~2015-06-29<br>1~1~600~2015-06-29<br>

Comment: this is my output.iwant to get 1~1~800~2015-06-29 this data then next line 1~1~500~2015-06-29 so on

Comment: are you trying to do it with nl2br or something? What is the encoding and type of the file also, just `\n` should do it for you.

Comment: i dont no about nl2br.file type is .txt

Comment: there must be something that is replacing `\n` with `<br/>`. This is the function that does it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: this change occur in the controller not in my .txt file

Comment: use before writing file: `str_replace("<br>","\n",$data)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81847/discussion-between-arthi-and-burak).